# Finding Writer of a file

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

suppose, I want to search for a text in some papers in pdf format and whenever I will find the text in any of those files, I want to print the title and writer's name of the paper.Normally We can search a keyword in a list of pdf files using the following command :

```
for file in *pdf; do 
pdftotext "$file" - | grep keyword
done
```

what additional things will I have to add to get the desired result?

Comment: Where is the author information written?  How is the data formatted?  Please specify.

Comment: Genarally in a research paper, the title is at the top of the paper, then below this is the author's name. we can use pdfinfo file.pdf command to get the details of the pdf file including author's name, title etc. My question is how I will link this info with my search result? @ Ned64

Answer (score 3):

You need an `if` and do something more if your `grep` succeeds:

```
for file in *pdf; do 
  if (pdftotext "$file" - | grep --quiet keyword); then
    echo match in "$file" ...
    pdfinfo "$file"
    echo ------------------------------
    # or whatever
  fi
done
```

Comment: if I want to manually display the title and the author, without using pdfinfo, what will I have to do? @Ned64

Comment: That will only be possible if you can automatically detect the data in the `pdftotext` output.  So, if it is always the 2nd and 3rd line, or always the first line that has a "*" character, and the line following, or whatever.  That could be turned into an algorithm.  If you have articles published in different journals/conferences I doubt that you can find a simple rule covering every variant.  So, the first step is that you study several `pdftotext` outputs to find rules.